# script shell in cronjob

Tags: shell, cron

I was working on crontab, but I think it gives me a problem. When I run my script in crontab it work but it is empty, and when I execute my script manually, if it contains data.

Can you help me?

regards

Comment: Your question needs to include enough information to allow it to be solved *inside the question itself*. Consider trying to build a minimal, complete, verifiable example as described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: that said, you might consider reviewing the existing question [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)

Comment: Actually, with the `%` signs referenced in a comment on the existing answer, it's likely that this is a duplicate of [How to test crontab entry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009759/how-to-test-crontab-entry)

Comment: Thanks Charles for the support.